# How to update a mongodb string field from command line?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

I am trying to update a field from command line (NOT from mongo shell)

```
mongo mydb --eval "db.users.update({}, { $set : {  email : "email@email.com" } })"
```

results into

```
Fri Oct 24 12:23:46.102 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Again trying

```
mongo mydb --eval "db.users.update({}, { $set : {  email : \"email@email.com\" } })"
```

same results

```
Fri Oct 24 12:24:05.559 JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any help for the same ?

Comment: had updated the question entirely. but thanks to Neil Lunn for pointing out. now i have updated this question back to previous one. and asked another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543376/how-to-pass-command-string-in-nodejs-childprocess-exec-function-to-update-a-stri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically just quoting. The shell is generally more forgiving internally but does expect valid JSON otherwise:

```
mongo mydb --eval "db.users.update({}, { '$set': {  'email' : 'email@email.com' } })"
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: mydb
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Actually, to play more nicely with other modifiers such a `multi` then reverse the type of quotes used:

```
mongo mydb --eval 'db.users.update({}, { "$set": {  "email": "email@email.com" } },{ "multi": true })
```

Comment: you answer is absolutely perfect. But actually my core requirement is little different for the question i asked previously. please review the question again.

Comment: @Koka You should ask a different question rather than change your question. But why use a command process when you could just use the driver to connect to the database and issue an update?

Comment: actually i am having 100s of other mongodb operations to perform over approx 10 databases, so i thought using a mongo shell script is better approach.

Comment: IMO first question had no special significance as you answered in question 'This is basically just quoting'.. and also my requirement is little different than what i asked in first question. But i will keep in mind not repeat this mistake again.

Comment: @Koka No it will not be a better approach and in fact far worse. You should ask another question to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Yes i gonna ask another question. But just for little guidance from your side, what to do with this question.. wont there be another duplicate, if i ask another one.

Comment: @Koka as for your opinion. It is extremely rude to ask "what colour is the sky?" and then come back after you have been answered and say "I mean on Jupiter" which is basically what you have done here. These are two separate questions.

Comment: thanks for pointing out .. i have updated this question back to previous one. and asked another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543376/how-to-pass-command-string-in-nodejs-childprocess-exec-function-to-update-a-stri